# CSS Flex: Is it possible to 'align-item: stretch' the child item that belongs to another container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm exploring flex css and stumble on this problem. I know that `align-items: stretch` could make the child elements pick the tallest child height and automatically stretch its siblings.

Based on the code below, is it possible to make the `component-item` stretch or have the same height as the other `component-item` using css? I need the other `component-item` to follow the 5 liner description height.

Thanks in advance!

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="component-container">
        <h1>Component Title</h1>
        <div class="component-item">
            3 liner description
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="component-container">
        <h1>Component Title</h1>
        <div class="component-item">
            5 liner description
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="component-container">
        <h1>Component Title</h1>
        <div class="component-item">
            4 liner description
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is this closed? The solution provided doesn't work on IE browser. Maybe this is a good solution in the future when `display:subgrid` is fully supported across the browsers.

Comment: from the duplicate : *This is not possible at present (2019/06) with any CSS layout method. display:subgrid solves the issue but it has limited non-experimental adoption by browsers as yet.* <-- Note the : this is not possible

Comment: @TemaniAfif definitely not a duplicate. This is using flex box not `display:grid`.  Why do you even close the issue when your suggested solution doesn't work.

Comment: This is not possible with **any CSS layout method.**. Flexbox, CSS grid, float, inline-block,table, etc all of them are different CSS layout and the only close solution to achieve  what you want is CSS grid.

Comment: Then don't flag this as duplicate and leave this open. There could be a work around for this and i'm open to suggestions.